# Don't boot shortly after upgrading to 20.04 - but can launch startx manually on recovery mode

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, xorg, lightdm, gdm

- Using Kubuntu with Gnome installed (I think this is Ubuntu with extra steps but it's work computer, I did not choose flavor)
- Computer is Lenovo T440P with 16 Go RAM (Core i5, integrated GPU)
- Upgraded OS from 16.04 to 20.04 this week because of depracating software
- All was good
- This morning, computer won't start, Kubuntu logo running in circle. Pressing ESC and see `(1 of 3) A start job is running for /devdata (8min 30 / no limit)` and alternating between three folders (`/devdata`, `/opt/devtools_admin` and `/opt/devtools`).
- I thought it was the problem but I think there is something else, this is just the point where it is stuck - but maybe not. If I use Alt+F2, I have the same message and no prompt.
- Reboot on recovery mode. Tried a bunch of things, upgrading packets, autoremove, etc, nothing do.
- As a hunch I start a root console and uses `su - myname` then `startx`
- Surprise, session opens but with XFCE instead of my Gnome. GUI is visually broken but mostly usable.
- I see graphic card is installed but not used, (UNCLAIMED), which is Intel Graphic 4600 (i915)
- Second display does not work (using vesa drivers, I guess you only have one main screen)
- I tried many, many things with Xorg, ending up deleting `~/.Xauthority` and all `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*.xorg.conf` ; reinstalling xserver-org reading many many many threads and posts
- Changed grub options many times, ending up removing all options, basically
- end up installing linux-headers-oem-20.04 (Kernel 5.14.0-1029-oem)
- Don't really know what I'm doing
- But this time after reboot (but still in always recovery mode) the graphic card is working, resolution improved and the second screen is alive.
- But the boot still stuck on the same loop.
- Tried to restore session manager to gdm3, then to lightdm, nothing changes
- Could run gnome by doing `gnome-shell --replace` on top of XFCE
- System works, but GUI is funny (window have no margin, colors are funny in a sad way)
- Cannot open computer without starting recovery mode, then root console, then opening my session manually, then lauching startx, then gnome and having partially working environment.
- Tried to change boot options with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`, same result (`start job` running around three folders, `/devdata`, `/opt/devtools_admin` and `/opt/devtools` which exists and are all empty

Do you have guidance or advices ? Should I reinstall a new version ? It is frustrating because it look like everything kinda works, but the session manager don't launch (lightdm?).

I use linux all the time but this is far above my competences. I would have provided more input but I using another computer to start this thread, if you need informations, I will provide.

Any suggestion, including changing session / window manager is welcome, as well as guidance about reinstallation without loosing data and configuration.

Thanks for your time and you help.

[EDIT]

- Following a suggestion from a fellow contributor to my question, i did `$ systemctl list-units --all` in order to find out what are those jobs. I got those relevant lines :

`opt-devtools.mount   loaded    failed     failed    /opt/devtools`

`opt-devtools_admin.mount  loaded    inactive   dead   /opt/devtools_admin`

`devdata-data.mount   loaded    inactive   dead      /devdata/data`

- I tried to `systemctl disable` but no changes after reboot. To avoid messing with services I don't really understand, i went no further down this road.
- I did tried to launch manually the job with `systemctl start opt-devtools.mount`, which failed, so I did `journalctl -xe` to have a report :

```
xb_builder_node_unlink: assertion 'XB_IS_BUILDER_NODE (self)' failed
Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
automatically prevented from changing kind on system/snap/*/desktop/chromium-browser.desktop/latest/stable from desktop
```

- I reckoned that it could be related to chromium and devtools (?) so I remove the package from the system.
- While I was at it , I also completely removed snap, because it wrongly looked related to the issue, with absolutely no effect.

[EDIT]
After some investigation, I run `systemctl status opt-devtools.mount` and in the details I noticed that the instructions looked referenced in /etc/fstab

So I did check the file and find some what looked like network NFS folders :

`baie01g.bed1t.local:/vol/devteam/devtools    /opt/devtools_admin  nfs    rw,bg,vers=3,tcp,timeo=600,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,hard,intr      0 0`

I don't know why they are here nor why it broke suddendly, but after commenting those line, I manage to get into a proper login prompt in a terminal.

I reinstalled gnome using `sudo apt --reinstall install gnome-shell gdm` and if I run `systemctl start gdm`, it works again, I could log in with the manager and get back to my desktop.

So now I guess it is solved, I just to find a way to start gdm with the proper right automatically.